# Link a .lib and using .dll in Windows in C++ in Eclipse

Tags: c++, twitter, dll, shared-libraries, libraries

I am trying the library usin Twitters APIs, I am using Eclypse on Windows usin MinGW , and I dont know how to do the 3 and 5 step. I linked the library on  Propierties >> C++ Build >> MINGW C+ + Linker >> libraries , I put on libraries "twitcurl" and in path  the direction of the project where is the library. ( Dont know if I did as i have to do it) 
the steps on the wiki are :

---

1) Download twitcurl source from http://twitcurl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/libtwitcurl using SVN clients like TortoiseSVN.

2) Open twitcurl.sln solution using Visual C++ 2008 (or later). Build the library twitcurl.lib.

3) Statically link twitcurl.lib in your application. Do not forget to include twitcurl.h, oauthlib.h and cURL headers in your application, as mentioned in How to use twitcurl library? section above.

4) Build your application.

5) Since cURL depends on OpenSSL, you need to copy libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll files to the same directory where your application executable is located.

Note: libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll can be copied from twitterClient\Release directory, or downloaded from http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win32-ssl-devel-msvc page.

---

I dont know where to copy the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll . It says on the executable, where is the executable ? . Maybe this questions look dumb, but I really dont know what to do :s.

Will means a lot your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it since nobody wanted to help me, if someone sees this post and need help . You have to I link the library on Propierties >> C++ Build >> MINGW C+ + Linker >> libraries , I put on libraries "twitcurl" and in path the direction of the project where is the library.

Second this tutorial is good : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLy69V2F_8M&t=240s

and if you want to install the lib use this wiki 
https://code.google.com/archive/p/twitcurl/wikis/WikiCompileMinGWWindows.wiki

you have to click on the C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\username , theres a .bat file that is the MinGW Shell, now write this code = "cd /curl " then you can proceed with the wiki and do all the functions it says you have to do .

Answer (score 0):

This is a naming convention, first rename the library, for example XXX.dll to libXXX.a; then add the path and the library name to the linker, library name is XXX and path could be a location in project workspace where the renamed library is stores.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file from XXX.dll to libXXX.a add the library to the linker as XXX so it will look for the libXXX.a file, add the path to the linker of the renamed file in a location, link as static, and finally copy the original file XXX.dll to the path where the exe file is stored, both Debug and Release. Dll works on CDT Eclipse for WIndows.